# How to make terraform's version immutable with atlantis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, version, terraform-provider-aws

I use [Atlantis](https://www.runatlantis.io/) to run Terraform's task.

In a terraform file, I'm setting AWS provider as this version:

```terraform
terraform {
  required_version = "0.13.5"

  required_providers {
    aws = "3.13.0"
  }
}
```

This is in one of multiple tasks. Other task like

```terraform
terraform {
  required_version = "0.14.9"

  required_providers {
    aws = "3.35.0"
  }
}
```

Atlantis' workflow setting as

```
dir: myproj/dev workspace: default
```

After some days, the Atlantis server checks for new tasks caused the version issue when run `terraform init`:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "3.13.0, >= 2.68.*, >= 2.42.*, >= 3.28.*, >= 2.68.*, >= 2.49.*, >= 2.49.*"...
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching "3.1.0, >= 3.1.*, >= 2.2.*"...
- Using hashicorp/random v3.1.0 from the shared cache directory

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
no available releases match the given constraints 3.13.0, >= 2.68.*, >= 2.42.*, >= 3.28.*, >= 2.68.*, >= 2.49.*, >= 2.49.*
```

Should I always update the new version for `aws` module manually? Is there any way if don't upgrade `3.13.0` version to the newest?

Comment: Are you saying you use the same directory/workspace for 2 different terraform configs? That isn't going to work well. I'm not sure how Atlantis does things but are you 'cleaning' its working directory before it runs the init/plan/apply?

Comment: @TerrySposato Good suggestion. They are using the same terraform configs.

Comment: How do you have the same config using 2 different versions of terraform? That is impossible, no? Also 2 different competing versions of a provider? Does whatever you are trying to do work outside of Atlantis?

Comment: I just set different terraform versions in different modules. For example, in root module, use version 1, in a sub module use version 2. Every time terraform will init/play/apply due to the prepared version file in the folder. Outside Atlantis should be the same, I didn't try it.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it would work. In any case, I would try and achieve what you are trying to do outside Atlantis first, then at least you know if something isn't working it's not something specific to terraform.

Comment: @TerrySposato I will try it if possible. But Atlantis is running on a center server and I didn't get a way to test it on local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the terraform version in atlantis.yaml

Exemple:

```
version: 3
projects:
  - name: my-project-1
    dir: ./my-project-1
    terraform_version: "0.13.5"
  - name: my-project-2
    dir: ./my-project-2
    terraform_version: "0.14.9"
```